Proof that two systems are equivalent
I was wondering if someone could help me with the proper answer for this? Below is the question and my solution. I was hoping for partial points but I don't know what can be marked partially correct here.



Where is your x(n) in all the equations? Key piece is that a unit step function with a gain of a unit step function is still the unit step function.

Start here. Skip Lecture 1. It should only take Lecture 2. Nothing more is really needed. If you think about it.

You have written right the names of the systems and one can extract from your writings the right impulse response of System 2. You only didn't know or forgot to say that it's the impulse response.
Looks like you do not have a slightest idea what's the impulse response of System 1. It needs convolution.
There's included promises of 5 and 15 points - maybe for showing a hint of understanding what systems 1 and 2 do in math.
Not asked, but I assume you had a table of common Z-transforms available in the exam. Z-domain transfer functions of the  blocks are simple and for that reason the Z-domain transfer functions of systems 1 and 2 are also simple and showing they are the same is elementary.
Here's the right line of the Z-transform table (source=Wikipedia)


First compute the z-transforms
$$h(z)=\frac{4 z}{4 z-3}$$
$$g(z)=\frac{4 z}{4 z+3}$$
The transfer function of system 1 is
$$\frac{7}{16} \ g(z) \ h(z)=\frac{7 z^2}{16 z^2-9}$$
And that of system 2 is
$$\frac{7}{32} \ (g(z)+h(z))=\frac{7 z^2}{16 z^2-9}$$
